# Report to get execution time of each function call based on parameters

Tags: function, time

I am using Visual studio diagnostic tool to get the time spent on eacgh funcion call during debugging.
Is there any way to get the report of time spent on each function call along with parameter passed to it?

In Visual studio IDE can i have a report or information of how much time is spent in a function, based on its parameters.

Let’s say I have the following function called SomeFun:

```
        public Function SomeFun(p1 As Integer, p2 As Double, ...) As Double
  'returns a value based on the parameters.
     end function
```

Expected report:

```
Function name - "SomeFun" :
p1      p2      …   No of Calls  Time
1       4       …       220     500ms
4       7.2     …       400     800ms
5       8       …       309     1024ms
7       8.2     …       542     600ms
.       .       .       .       .
.       .       .       .       .
.       .       .       .       .
```

Is there any other options to get the time spent on each function call based on parameter ?